# Tables/Listings: Convert Markdown to HTML & PDF with Pandoc

Tags: html, latex, markdown, pandoc

I want use pandoc for convert a Markdown document to two formats: HTML and PDF.

While HTML conversion works okay, with PDF conversion I have some problems with tables and listings:

- Long tables in HTML appears perfect, but on PDF shows a long table over document's margin. I want that table resize to his content.
- Long code in listings same problem: width too long.

How can I solve this problem?

**Note:** I need that a same Markdown file for HTML and PDF conversion.

Comment: you can modify the latex template pandoc uses to generate the pdf... see http://pandoc.org/README.html#templates

Comment: Thanks! I want recomendation for pandoc config/setup for generate HTML/PDF documents without changes on Markdown (with same markdown), where tables shows okay for both documents.